# *** Caught segfault *** address 0x0, cause "memory not mapped error

Tags: r, macos, installation, homebrew, xquartz

I am trying to install rattle on macOS Catalina but every time I enter `rattle()` in R, I get the following error message:

> Loading required package: RGtk2
> *** Caught segfault *** address 0x0, cause "memory not mapped.

I have tried installing homebrew, macports,XQuartz but still same issue. I have installed latest packages but still not go. In other words I have gotten it to work at all if thats any help. New install.

[image]

Comment: Might be some problems with the dependency RGtk2.. Did you try to reinstall that?

Comment: Yes I reinstalled RGtk2